# Why 0 === -0 is true, but 1/0 === 1/-0 is false?

Tags: javascript

```
var a = 0;
var b = -a;
```

When I post the following code to console I got `true`:

```
console.log(a === b); // true
```

But when I do some calculation with it I got `false`:

```
console.log(1/a === 1/b); // false
```

Why is it so?

Comment: Because `Infinity` and `-Infinity` aren't equal?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, mathematically speaking 1/0 != Infinity. It is undefined.

Comment: I'm not seeing a really strong reason for downvoting this question. Yes, if you try `1 / 0` and `1 / -0` in the console, you'll see `Infinity` and `-Infinity`, and if you look in the specification, you'll find that although `0` and `-0` are considered equal, `Infinity` and `-Infinity` are not. But it's a complex area, it doesn't seem unreasonable to ask about it.

Comment: @SumnerEvans this isn't maths, it's JavaScript!

Comment: Basically, because IEEE 754-2008 says so.

Comment: You can use `Object.is` to distinguish `-0` from `0`.

Comment: Yes, @Bergi, in some sort of complex calculation I think that `Object.is` is much better to use then `===`.

Comment: @DmitriyLoskutov: Nah. You really will expect them to compare equal in your calculations. Notice that `x*0 == 0` is true for all (non-NaN, non-infinite) numbers, but `Object.is(x*0, 0)` is not. There's a good reason why `===` is the default :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because `Infinity == -Infinity` is false, as per abstract equality comparison algorithm.

`1/0` will yield `Infinity` at the same time `1/-0` Yields `-Infinity`. So both are not are not equal and thus returning `false`.